# Crossfit training plans: progressive programming of fitness and skills

Tags: crossfit, programming

Are there any high quality examples of progressive crossfit training plans over a longer period of time say a few month or a year?

Starting at an assumed fitness and skill level, it should be desined in such a way that it progressively builds skills, strength, power, endurance and flexiblity.

I didn't find anything like that by searching the web, just blogs like wodstar or from invictus crossfit to follow along without any regognizable progresssion. Perhaps there are any publications in books or journals about that.

Comment: The closest I know of are [Dave Werner's skill levels](http://www.crossfitseattle.com/athletic-skill-levels/) and [Nicki Violetti's CrossFit on-ramp](http://www.catalystathletics.com/article/54/CrossFit-On-Ramp/).

Comment: There is a lot to be said about the community of cross-fit being the main benefit of doing the sport. Is there a club near you?

Comment: JJosaur: I am member of a crossfit box already, but that's not the point of my question. I just wanted to study plans and program design principles to improve my background knowledge. However I didn't find almost no published quality material about that. So I asked this question.

Comment: The reason you can't find information is because crossfit is not really designed to progress individuals to improve in an individualised fashion through appropriate or sequential programming. The nature and culture of crossfit thrives on direct competition, atmosphere, everyone performing the same WODs (though with individualised parameters) and training for chaos rather than directing your efforts on particular skills.

To progressively build skill, strength, power, endurance and flexibility you won't find the most efficient answer in crossfit, though it can be done.

Comment: If your goals to attain better fitness, lift more and gain strength, endurance and skills through crossfit then have you talked to who runs your crossfit box? They will probably have recommendations, you are paying them for their training, after all.

Answer (score 1):

What are your goals with crossfit?

Compete in the open?

Attain better fitness?

Lift more?

Lose/gain weight/strength?

Many crossfitters complain about the lack of balance in workout plans, so you may find that the best course of action is to create your own plan based on the style of crossfit. This is not recommended for beginners, because this may lead to an unhealthy combination of exercises in the same workout, but you said 'assumed fitness and skill level' so I'm assuming that you aren't a beginner. My favorite websites that I find helpful for assessing the strengths and weaknesses of crossfit so that I can formulate my own workout plans based on what pre-made plans don't give me are breakingmuscle.com and theboxmag.com. Both have pre-made workout plans available online, they may be what you are looking for, or they may provide some insight for making your own. Check out the crossfit open prep plans on breaking muscle if you want a long, continuous plan. Both have articles on how to improve your fitness based on crossfit, not to mention both are full of good reading and insight on anything crossfit related or what makes a balanced workout. If you don't find any help here, consider heading to a local box to ask if they can help you come up with something. Most boxes take an interest in other crossfitters, even if you don't workout with them. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I don' want to compete at the open. And yes I am not a beginner but want to attain better fitness, lift more and gain strength, endurance and skills. However the question ist not restricted to plans to a specific level. I am looking for beginner plans as well as for training plans for crossfit games athletes. In some part I just want it out of curiosity on the other part I want to study them and adapt something for my own.

Comment: To fit more to the Q&A format of stackexchange, you may consider to move your questions to a comment.

Comment: Please can you share the links to the plans on breakingmuscle and theboxmag you have in mind?